# Executing PHP on button click

Tags: javascript, php

I have a form containing data in PHP. There are two buttons Edit and Delete, both performing edit and delete option in mysql . How can I add links to two different PHP pages and also pass data to them. For single button, we can use submit type and action tag, but how to do this easily for two buttons

Comment: share some code that you tried

Comment: You should change form action with querystring '?edit=1' or create hidden field to store edit true/false before submiting form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two ways to do it.

Way 1:
You can combine both php files into one file and differentiate the process based on the post value of button.

Ex

```
<form action="filename.php" method="post">
.
.
.
<input type="submit" name="edit"/>
<input type="submit" name="delete"/>
</form>
```

filename.php

```
if(isset($_POST["edit"]))
{
//do edit process here
}
else if(isset($_POST["delete"]))
{
//do delete process here
}
```

Way 2:
Use ajax and submit values to two different PHP files and execute it

Comment: I am beginner to PHP, can u share me some links of doing it through way 1 and 2 both